# What are some creative ideas for a photo-shoot centering around the use of a notebook computer?

Tags: artwork, people

So, I have to create an interesting photo with the subject being the use of a laptop. It should be as interesting as possible.

I have thought of a photo with working on laptop while going up on stairs in the metro. Can you suggest some ideas, or maybe some photographers who have a related work.

Comment: Hi Ryan. I'm curious — is this a homework assignment, or a business client request? No problem either way; just wondering.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be interesting to portray the laptop being used in places where you do not expect to see a laptop: say a kitchen (with food splattered on it), a field (with dirt on it), or even a sporting event, say on a football field.

Good luck!

Comment: Underwater, while scuba diving?

Answer (score 1):

Does the laptop have to be the focus? There was a series done a while ago by Gabriela Herman on bloggers, it's up here [on her site](http://www.gabrielaherman.com/photos/bloggers/#)

Comment: not necesarily, the focus must be a special environment in which you work on your laptop... But thanks:) Maybe you or others could give me some more resources.

Comment: You could focus on the environments you see people working with laptops, coffee shops, trains, buses etc that aren't the traditional office/home office environments. If I was doing it I'd probably do something like get someone to sit in a coffee shop and do a really long exposure to get everyone blurred around them whilst they sit still and are zoned in.